# C# .net Is there a better way to count list multiple times in class?

Tags: c#, .net

I have property like this:

```
private int _Counter;
public int Counter;
{ 
    get { return _Counter; }
    set { _Counter = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
)
```

and in the class I have to check Counter value multiple times after some actions

```
Counter = List.Where(item => item.State.ToUpper() = "SOME STATE").Count();
```

1. do I always have to call the whole line of code above to count list or there is a simple way ? put the code stright into property or something

2. can I put properties that are common to the, for example ViewModelBase and then inherit it in other classes ?

thanks

Comment: 1.  `public int Counter => List.Where(item => item.State.ToUpper() = "SOME STATE").Count();`  is the shortest way, though it doesn't implement `PropertyChanged` (I use Fody.PropertyChanged).

Comment: 2.  Yes. ........

Comment: Yes you can put the code into a property or a private method, and call those.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you have a UI element to display the updated count, which is derived from a specific counting logic

In that case, your Count could be on the BaseViewModel, but it may be simply

```
public virtual int Counter;
{ 
    get ;
    set ;
)

public ObservableCollection<YourType> Items {get;set;}
```

your inherited ViewModel will have another field

```
public override int Count { 
    get => _Count;
    set => this.SetPropertyChanged (ref _Count, "Count"); // if using Prism 
}
```

Now you want to have something in your child view model to listen to the OnCollectionChange and then announce the Count change by setting

```
this.Count = // your counting logic
```

So, I don't really see a need to set this value multiple times, unless I miss something from what you are trying to achieve